# How do I easily select an image using CKeditor and just get the URL

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want something like wordpress has with the select featured image, where all it does is save the URL for the image you select. Just something simple and to the point. I don't need any other toolbar buttons or options.

using CKeditor 4.4.7

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly do you want (and why).

CKEditor itself doesn't have the feature of viewing & selecting 3rd party images. Some file manager should be integrated for that. See the list of popular ones here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor

If you want something simpler, look how these tools are made and develop your version. Did I answer you question?